# How to efficiently implement BS2 .spanX semantics in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

The `.spanX` classes in Bootstrap 2 (bs2) were always the same size, regardless of nesting level.  To implement this at the top-level is straight-forward:

```
// top level .spanX
.generate-level1(@index) when (@index >= 1) {
    .span@{index}   { .make-md-column(@index); }
    .offset@{index} { .make-md-column-offset(@index); }
    .generate-level1(@index - 1);
}
.generate-level1(12);
```

The next level down is a bit more complicated, e.g. the bs2 nesting where two `.span4` equally split the enclosing `.span8`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4"></div>
            <div class="span4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

which would be equivalent to the following in bs3 (where each row has 12 "units" regardless of nesting level):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

a `.span4` inside a `.span8` must then be `4 * 12 / 8 = 6`, which I'm generating like this:

```
.generate-level2(@parent) when (@parent >= 1) {
    .generate-spans(@child) when (@child >= 1) {
        .span@{parent} .span@{child}   { .make-md-column(12*@child/@parent); }
        .span@{parent} .offset@{child} { .make-md-column-offset(12*@child/@parent); }
        .generate-spans(@child - 1);
    }
    .generate-spans(@parent);
    .generate-level2(@parent - 1);
}
.generate-level2(12);
```

I have two questions..

Q1: How would I go about generating level 3 (e.g. `.span8 .span4 .span2`)?

Q2: The generated css is very repetitive:

Plain `.span8`

```
.span8 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .span8 {
    float: left;
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
}
```

..plain `.span4`...

```
.span4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .span4 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

.. nested `.span8 .span4` ...

```
.span8 .span4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .span8 .span4 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make the css less verbose/repetitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your Q1, i don't think you can avoid having a lot of classes when you want to generate all possible opportunities. Generating all classes also does not make your code more semantic i think so.

But you can use the list functions (see: http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions) maybe to generate the semantic widths:

```
.setwidths(@levels;@width:100%;@level:1;@columns:12) when (length(@levels) >= @level){
.setwidths(@levels;  @width * ( extract(@levels,@level) / @columns ); @level + 1;  extract(@levels,@level));
}
.setwidths(@levels;@width;@level;@columns) when (default()){
width: @width;
}
property {
.setwidths(6 4 2);
}
```

In the above the `.setwidths(6 4 2);` call sets the width for the third level (span6 > span4 > span 2)

Than Q2:

if you HTML may, non semantic, contain grid classes you can use a base class:

.span {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

with in your HTML: `class="span span{X}"`

or when you use the `:extend` pseudo class, see http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature, you should be able to create a (long) list of selector which share the same list of properties, for instance:

```
.selector {
&:extend(.span);
.setwidths(6 4 2);
}
```

Notice that attribute selectors can be use as an alternative for base classes:

```
[class^="span"], [class*=" span"] {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Bootstrap itself avoids (partial) attribute selectors because of performance issues. See also: http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/